# Boolean expression with integer increments gives unexpected results

Tags: c, increment, boolean-expression, side-effects

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    int main()
    {
       int x, y, z; 
       x=y=z=1; 
       z = ++x || ++y && ++z; 
       printf("%d, %d, %d", x, y,z);
       return 0;
    }
```

I am getting output 2, 1, 1. I need and explanation why Y is 1 in output?

Comment: Because you're running some other program, and not this one. You can't be executing this program. none of the variables could possibly be less than 3.

Comment: Is this C or C++, because it can't be two languages at the same time.  Please remove incorrect tag.

Comment: That's strange, I get output `4, 3, 1`.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik `z` can as it is a result of boolean operation. Update: And the OP have changed their mind..

Comment: Ok, with a possible exception of z.

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake. Now code is correct. Why I am getting 1 for Y?

Comment: I'm assuming it's because of short-circuiting

Comment: @OldProgrammer Is this not valid C++? If it is, is the tag not perfectly in order? If there are differences in the way the two languages treat the expression, would it not be enlightening to discuss them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `||` operator is **short-circuiting;** the right operand is not evaluated (and side effects never executed, i.e. the variables never incremented) if the left operand evaluates to != 0.

(Remember that "multiplication comes before addition", or in boolean logic AND comes before OR. Because of the operator precedences the expression becomes, fully bracketed, `(++x) || ((++y) && (++z))`; in other words, everything to the right of `||` is the OR's ignored right hand side.)

The evaluation of the left operand `++x` increments `x` to 2. `z` is assigned the boolean value of the result of `||` which is 1, as it was all along.

---

As an aside, gcc warned and I think it is true that the statement is also **undefined behavior.** The C 11 standard draft [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) says in 6.5/2:

> If a side effect on a scalar object is unsequenced relative to [...] 
>   a value computation using the value of the same scalar
>   object, the behavior is undefined.

The standard gives the example of `i = ++i + 1;` for this. In your right hand side expression `z` plays that role. The side effect is the increment, the value computation is the `&&` sub-expression.

---

<sup>1</sup> It is possible (i.e. I'm not sure) that it is defined as long as the right hand side is never evaluated. In that case the compiler would be allowed to assume that `++x`  is never 0 and omit the test. The generated code for the complicated boolean expression would just boil down to an increment of x.

Answer (score 2):

The part `|| ++y && ++z` is not evaluated, because `++x` is already true. See

[Short circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation/)

Answer (score 1):

The logical operation `||` is so-called "short-circuit" or "lazy" operation.
If the left operand of such an operator is evaluating to logical `true` or a non-zero, the right operand won't be evaluated.

So in your case:

```
z = ++x || ++y && ++z;
```

`++x` is evaluating to `2`, making `x` equal `2`. This is non-zero, so everything on the right side is not evaluated, so `y` and `z` are not incremented. And `z` is assigned by the result of the *logical* `OR` operation, i.e. `1`. And this is what you see.